# Understanding Filling array with Random Numbers (Big Java Ex 7.4)

Tags: java, arrays

**Problem Statement**

> Write a program that produces random permutations of the numbers 1 to
>   10. To generate a random permutation, you need to fill an array with the numbers 1 to 10 so that no two entries of the array have the same
>   contents. You could do it by brute force, by calling Random.nextInt
>   until it produces a value that is not yet in the array. Instead, you
>   should implement a smart method. Make a second array and fill it with
>   the numbers 1 to 10. Then pick one of those at random, remove it, and
>   append it to the permutation array. Repeat 10 times. Implement a class
>   PermutationGenerator with a method int[] nextPermutation

I'm having some trouble understanding what the question is saying.

My interpretation is that we need to put the numbers 1-10 in array, given some random numbers which can range from one to ten.

The way I would solve this is by simply adding to an array and doing a loop and just check whether the next random number is already within the array. However as per the question, this is considered "brute force"

I'm not exactly sure what my book is saying by implementing a second array. If I make a second array won't I still have to check whether something is in the array?

**My Attempt**
First I'm just trying to put 10 random numbers into an array, and ignoring the part about that they have to be distinct. Heres what i have

```
private int[] arr;
private Random randNum;

public seq()
{
    randNum = new Random();
    arr = new int[10];
}

public int getRandNum()
{
    int newNum = randNum.nextInt(10)+1;
    return newNum;
}

public int [] filledArr()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = getRandNum();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The problem with this is that I would have to call `getRandNum()` 10 times to get 10 different numbers, and then call `filledArr` to put it inside. This is ALOT of typing. Is there a better way? I guess I could also make a for loop inside the main, and do this? This seems horribly inefficient.

Thanks for any Advice

**Another
Attempt**

```
class seq
{
    private int[] arr;
    private int[] filledArr;
    private Random randNum;

    public seq()
    {
        randNum = new Random();
        arr = new int[10];
        filledArr = new int[10];
    }

    public int [] generateNewArr()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i< 11 ; i++)
        {
            filledArr[i] = i;
        }
        return filledArr;
    }

    public int [] newArr()
    {
        for(int i=1; i < 11 ; i++)
        {
            int newRandNum = //RANDOM NUMBER IN filledArr;
            arr[i] = newRandNum;
            // REMOVE that random number from filledArr
        }
    }

}
```

**ATTEmPT WITH ARRAYLISTS**

```
 import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class seq
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrListOne;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrListTwo;
    private Random num;
    public seq()
    {
        num = new Random();
        arrListOne = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
        arrListTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
    }
    public ArrayList getFilledArr()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < arrListOne.size()+1 ; i++)
        {
            arrListOne.add(i);
        }
        return arrListOne;
    }
    public ArrayList randNewArr()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
        int randNum = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size())+1;
        arrListTwo.add(arrListOne.get(randNum));
        arrListOne.remove(arrListOne.get(randNum));
        }
        return arrListTwo;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "The Randomized ArrayList is";
        output+=arrListTwo;
        return output;
    }
}

public class Sequence
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    seq seqObj = new seq();
    seqObj.getFilledArr();
    seqObj.randNewArr();
    System.out.println(seqObj.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with the Problem Statement is common.  The first sentence defines the essential requirement.  The rest suggests how to solve it.  That section of the book is apparently focusing on arrays so it's a bit of an obtuse example - just be sure to clearly separate the problem that needs to be solved from how it will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is simply saying this:

> Make an array with numbers 1-10 (doesn't have to be randomly ordered). Then
>   generate a random number between 1-10 and pick the number and remove that index
>   from the array you created earlier.

A rough implementation would be:

```
ArrayList nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // The arraylist with numbers from 1-10
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++;)
    nums.add(i);

Random r = new Random();
int x = r.nextInt(10);

int[] finalNums = new int[2];
finalNums[0] = nums.get(x);
nums.remove(x); // Remove the number at this index so it won;t be picked up again

x = r.nextInt(9); // Since we removed one index from arraylist, so total elements are now nine instead of 10.
finalNums[1] = nums.get(x);
nums.remove(x);
```

So what's the difference? In this approach, you are sure that it won't pick same number twice. WHy? Because you remove the number as soon as you pick it so it has no change of getting picked up again.

**EDIT:**

As for your attempt with ArrayList where you have asked what you write in the `main` block, you simply have to call the two methods you created in class in order. It could either be in main block:

```
public class Sequence
{
    // You need one main method atleast to run the code
    public static void main(String[] args){
        seq seqObj = new seq();
        System.out.println(seq.getRandomArray());
    }
}
```

Or you could also call these methods in `seq` class' constructor:

```
public seq()
{
    randNum = new Random();
    arr = new int[10];
    filledArr = new int[10];
    this.getFilledArr();
    this.randNewArr();
}
```

Another thing to note, your method to display output of ArrayList is **not** okay. A little correction to your code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class seq
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrListOne;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrListTwo;
    private Random num;

    public seq()
    {
        num = new Random();
        arrListOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrListTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        getFillerArr();
        randNewArr();
    }

    // You dont have to return ArrayList here
    public void getFilledArr()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 11 ; i++)
        {
            arrListOne.add(i);
        }
    }

    // You dont have to return ArrayList here
    public void randNewArr()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            int randNum = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size())+1;
            arrListTwo.add(arrListOne.get(randNum));
            arrListOne.remove(arrListOne.get(randNum));
        }
    }

    // A method that returns you random array list so you can easily use it following rules of encapsulation
    public ArrayList<Integer> getRandomArray() {
        return this.arrListTwo;
    }
}

public class Sequence
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        seq seqObj = new seq();
        System.out.println(seq.getRandomArray());
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

For your problem of `negative bound exception`, This is how your code should be:

```
    public seq()
    {
        num = new Random();

        // Do not try to specify size of Array List here. THey don't have fixed size.
        arrListOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrListTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        getFillerArr();
        randNewArr();
    }

    public void getFilledArr()
    {
        // Manually iterate for 10 elements.
        for(int i = 1; i < 11 ; i++)
        {
            arrListOne.add(i);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList randNewArr()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
        // Do not add +1 here, actual array size is already 1 less than the size you get from #size() method.
        int randNum = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size());
        arrListTwo.add(arrListOne.get(randNum));
        arrListOne.remove(arrListOne.get(randNum));
        }
        return arrListTwo;
    }
```

*Explanation:*

```
arrListOne = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
```

Here you are trying to create an array list of fixed size 10? But ArrayLists do not have a fixed size. So this won't work. Hence your this loop fails too:

```
public ArrayList getFilledArr()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < arrListOne.size()+1 ; i++)
    {
        arrListOne.add(i);
    }
    return arrListOne;
}
```

(array list has 0 size, so loop doesn't run).

Hence you get that exception when getting random number.

PS: My bad, been a while since I did java. Somehow I overlooked it while reading that code.

Comment: I;m going to try this, but I want to do it with arrays first. Could you see my most edited code in my question. I feel like im close!

Comment: Problem with simple array is that you can't just remove an element and index completely; which you can do easily in arraylist. Even in your edited code attempt #2, you are not removing index or adding any condition to filter that index from filledArr. Hence that index can surely be picked again which goes against conditions of your question.

Comment: Ok I also added an attempt with array lists.

Comment: @cresjoy I have "improved" your code for ArrayList implementation. I suggest you also read about `encapsulation` in java.

Comment: Great, it does indeed look good. I've modified my own code a bit. It gives me an error on the line  int randNum = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size())+1;, saying that n must be positive. What does this mean?

Comment: @cresjoy there, I added the explanation to your negative bound exception to my solution.

Comment: It works!!! Thanks soooo much! I wonder why it didn't give me an error when i put 10 then. It showed as if it was acceptable!

Comment: Also for your code, I dont think you need to return this.arrayListTwo right? Simply returing arrayListTwo is fine,no?

Comment: @cresjoy yes, you don't need `this` keyword. Its just a habit in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem with this is that I would have to call getRandNum() 10 times to get 10 different numbers, and then call filledArr to put it inside. This is ALOT of typing. Is there a better way?

Yes it's.

Use this :

```
public int [] filledArr()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = randNum.nextInt(10)+1;
    }

return arr;
}
```

so you're coding less and result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it seems you didn't understant the "smart" method suggested; it should proceed as follows:

1. Generate an array of 10 integers, **not randomly**, simply place all numbers ordered from 1 to 10.
   Also generate an empty array.
2. In a loop, pick a random element from the first array and move it to the second array.

Can you go on from here?

---

Edit: the main problems with your third attempt are:

In `int randNum = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size())+1;` you seem to be confusing two things, the value of the integer, and its position in the array. What you want to pick randomly in a range (starting from zero) is a *position*, hence you should write instead 
`int randPos = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size());`

Also, the structure of the class is not very nice, you are supposed to code a class with a `nextPermutation()` method, all the arrays/lists should live inside that method, the only `state` to held as fields inside the class should be the random generator. I suggest to code all in this structure:

```
public class PermGen {

    public final int SIZE = 10; 
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    /* returns a new permutation of elements from 1 to 10 (size) */
    public int[] nextPermutation() {
        // create the two lists/arrays here
        int[] res = new int[SIZE];
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // or LinkedList  
        // ... fill list1
        for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
           // pick a random pos1 from list, move the element to res
           // ...
           res[i] = list1.remove(randpos); // move the element  
        } 
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I don't want to look at the answers below just yet

Comment: Could you look at my attempt again that I put in the question... I feel like I'm very close!

Comment: Your second attemp is closer, but still needs work. In particular, I advice you to use `ArrayList` (or `LinkedList`) instead of `array` for the first (non random) array, because otherwise it's difficult to remove an element from it (and hence resize it).

Comment: Yes, if I use an arraylist I can simply use.remove. I haven't learned linkedlists yet. I wonder why the problem said to use an array then!

Comment: Hi, I tried writing a solution with arraylista and now I'm a bit stuck, can you look at my third edit?

Comment: Yup, you are right. However, it is giving me an error on the line int randNum = num.nextInt(arrListOne.size());, saying n must be positive.. Whats going on?

Comment: This is so frusturating -__-

Comment: Got it! You cant set an arrayList to a preset size!!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
int LEN = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> oldArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
   oldArray.add(i+1);
int[] newArray = new int[LEN];
for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
   int pos = (int)(Math.random() * oldArray.size());
   newArray[i] = oldArray.remove(pos);
}
```

Not sure if it meets the criteria (with the ArrayList and all, but just a suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Since this is a *homework* problem, obviously, I don't want to give you actual code but rather to describe it.</strike>   *(Since you said that it was not, I added a full Answer above, but decided to also keep this explanation.)*

Basically, you are "shuffling a deck of cards."  Start by initializing the array to sequential 1..10.

Now, you can "shuffle" the deck by looping through the deck from 1..10, selecting a card-number at random that is *greater than **or** equal to* ("at or ahead-of ...") your cursor position.  **Swap** the two cards.

This is functionally equivalent to "remove a card at random from another array," but it exploits the fact that that "pile of shuffled cards" grows at exactly the same rate as the "pile of sorted cards to randomly draw from" shrinks. Hence, it can all be done in just one array.  The shuffled portion is behind the cursor; the (initially) in-order portion is at-or-ahead.

In just *one* pass, you have an excellently shuffled deck of cards which is known to contain no duplicates.

Comment: The issue now is deleting the element from an array. I went back in my book and I remembered we set arrays to fixed length. Looks like ArrayLists are clearly easy to use here. i wonder why the problem said to use an array then.

Comment: You can do it with a simple array. The key notion is that you **swap** the two cards.  "You have first selected a card at-random from the semi-sorted half (the "upper half") of the array, and you now need to put that card at the cursor position. But, what do you do with the card that's there now?" Answer: you put it at the randomly-chosen position! ("Swap 'em.") The outcome is *identical* to "using two arrays." It will work fine with any type of container, but the underlying implementation of that container should be such that any randomly-chosen element can be retrieved with near-equal speed.

Comment: Ok I will try this out soon, I got a solution working with array lists. Looks a bit complex but I'll trace it by hand

Comment: I added an Answer which demonstrates the idea in pseudo-code, now that I know it isn't homework.  **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code *(not Java)*:

```
Card deck[], temp;
int i, j;

// fill the deck
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) deck[i] = i;

// Shuffle 'em.  Runs stern-to-stem because of 'rand()'
for (i = 9; i > 0; i--) {   // no need for (i == 0) ...
  j = rand(i);   // returns value in the inclusive range [0..i]

  // it's just fine if (i == j) ... although it usually won't be ...
  temp    = deck[i];    // set-aside the card in the cursor-position
  deck[i] = deck[j];    // replace it with the randomly-chosen card
  deck[j] = temp;       // then put the original card where it can get picked
}
```

As this version of the algorithm runs, the cards *beyond* the position of cursor `i` are shuffled cards, while the cards in `[0..i]` are the semi-sorted pool of cards from which to randomly draw. (This pool starts perfectly-sorted but becomes unsorted as elements get swapped into it, but who-cares.)

You will see that this algorithm, working in a *single* array in *one* pass, produces a thoroughly shuffled deck that contains no duplicates. The algorithm is *identical* to one that uses two arrays, but much more efficient:   the array is shuffled in-place and is never resized.

Any container-class (resizeable or not ...) can be used, but the chosen container should be of an underlying implementation that allows any randomly-selected element to be retrieved with comparable speed regardless of where it is. For instance, "a linked list" would not be an efficient choice.

Comment: Ahh, I got it! Pretty neat that you thought of this :)